# js localStorage for cycle includes empty string

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm creating site with weather information now. I have a special form (.html file) that adds new city with info as unordered list. I'm also using `localStorage` to save cities when user refreshed the page by accident.

`localStorage` stores only string as I know. When user adds new city, script updates `localStorage`. In order to to refresh the page, refresh button is provided.

When user refreshes the page, all cities are gone, so the script recovers all cities by that `localStorage`. Array value `[]` represented as String value `""` in JS. The problem is, when the script tries to restore cities, `""` value would also provided as city value.

Code:

```js
    let cities = [];
    if (localStorage.getItem("cities") !== null) {
        cities = localStorage.getItem("cities").split(',');
    }
    console.log("cities = " + cities);

    for (const city of cities) {
        if (city !== "" && !screen_cities.includes(city)) {
            const rnd = Math.random().toString();
            const code = await add_new_li(city, rnd);
            if (code === 1) {
                console.warn("for city " + city + " code is " + code);
                document.getElementById(rnd).remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

`Array.prototype.forEach` doesn't that, but I can't use it because of asynchronous function `add_new_li`.

Please help me.

Comment: how do you save to localStorage? via localStorage.setItem() ? without any JSON.stringify() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JSON.stringfy and JSON.parse, we can save object via `localStorage`

```
let cities = [];
if (localStorage.getItem("cities") !== null) {
    cities = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cities"))
}
console.log("cities = " + cities);

for (const city of cities) {
    if (city !== "" && !screen_cities.includes(city)) {
        const rnd = Math.random().toString();
        const code = await add_new_li(city, rnd);
        if (code === 1) {
            console.warn("for city " + city + " code is " + code);
            document.getElementById(rnd).remove();
        }
    }
}

// -------- save
cities.push('Shen Yang')
localStorage.setItem('cities', JSON.stringify(cities))
```